# PHP arrays - retrieving a value when other value is known

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of the following structure:

```
$some_array = array(
    array(
        'font' => 'Arial',
        'label' => 'Arial'
    ),
    array(
        'font' => 'PT+Sans:400',
        'label' => 'PT Sans'
    )
);
```

Let's say that I only know that one item has 'font' value of 'PT+Sans:400' and I need to retrieve the 'label' value of that single item. How can I do it easier than iterating through subarrays?

Comment: What's wrong with iterating through subarrays?

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong, other than trying to find out if there's any other solution for that.

Comment: How would you get to the item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already using `foreach` you just want other alternatives then you can consider this solutions

**Solution 1**

You can try to filter your search using `array_filter`

```
$search = "PT+Sans:400" ;
$array = array_filter($array,function($v)use($search){ return $v['font'] == $search;});
var_dump($array); // returns all found array
```

Output

```
array
  1 => 
    array
      'font' => string 'PT+Sans:400' (length=11)
      'label' => string 'PT Sans' (length=7)
```

If you need only the label

```
$find = array_shift($array); // take only the first
print($find['label']);  // output the label
```

Output

```
PT Sans
```

**Solution 2**

It you are not interested in return the array and all you want is just the label then you should consider `array_reduce`

```
$search = "PT+Sans:400" ;
$results = array_reduce($array,function($a,$b)use($search){ return $b['font'] == $search ? $b['label'] : null ; });
print($results);
```

Output

```
PT Sans
```

Comment: Not necessary the easier way, but at least an alternative. I wanted to learn something new and thus I did. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate through the subarrays. Alternatively, if you have control over the data structure where this is getting stored, consider using a hash table (associative array) and then you can just check if a particular key is set.

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple:

```
function findLabel($source, $font) 
{
    foreach ($source as $item) {
        if ($item['font'] == $font) {
            return $label;
        }
    }

    return null;    
}
```

Usage:

```
$label = findLabel($some_array, 'PT+Sans:400');
```

Comment: That's exactly how I do it right now, thought there might be some other way to perform that. Thanks for your replies guys.

Comment: There is other way .. what do you want  ... the label name or the full array

Comment: Just the 'label' value from the same subarray for which I already know the 'font' value.